# Is there a better way to handle loading arrays of images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, radio-button

I have groups of related images that I would like to be able to change (but position in the same div) by clicking on different radio buttons.

Currently I am using arrays to handle the html,

```
var marketingImages = [image1HTML, image2HTML, image3HTML, image4HTML];

var salaryImages = [image1HTML, image2HTML, image3HTML, image4HTML];
```

And when a relevant radio button is clicked, a function runs to clear the html in the div (of possible previous images), and load the new images using .append.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#marketing, #salary").click(leed);

    function leed() {

        $("#portfolio-images").html("");

        if ($("#marketing").is(':checked')) {

            var portfolioArray = marketingImages;

        } else if ($("#salary").is(':checked'))  {

            var portfolioArray = salaryImages;

        }

        for (var i=0; i<portfolioArray.length; i++) {
            $("#portfolio-images").append(portfolioArray[i]);
        }
        ...
}
```

It seems to work well, but being a noob though I have to wonder if there's a better way to handle this. Technically these images are just thumbnails (that can be clicked on to load larger Lightbox versions), but I'm unsure of how well that would "really" load for someone.

Does somebody know if there's a better way to handle loading groups of images? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure but to get a better performance, you could reuse the existing image DOM elements by just changing the source attribute. Instead of creating it each and every time. However, there will be some occasions when you will not have enough image elements, which you will then need to add. Or other occasions where you will need to remove. (BTW I am saying I am not sure because the level of performance optimisation depends on the platform u are targeting.)

Comment: Interesting. So you're thinking putting <img>'s in the .html file but changing their .src's from JS? (Platform-wise, I'm just thinking desktop/laptops essentially [if that is a relevant answer to "platform"].)

Comment: I would think that the amount of time the javascipt is going to take to execute will be trivial no matter how you set this up.  Maybe rather than removing the existing images you could just hide them so they don't need to be reloaded every time someone clicks the radio button. Lazy-loading the images would be ideal.  The perfomance implications of loading less images will be way more significant than any javascript micro-optimization.

Comment: "Maybe rather than removing the existing images you could just hide them so they don't need to be reloaded every time someone clicks the radio button." That sounds like a good idea, but can you give me an example of how I could accomplish that? Can I check to see if the current HTML already contains the array of images?

Comment: Alright, I *think* I'm onto something, perhaps less complex than I thought it would be. Thanks everyone who posted.